# Nearest non adjacent point

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgresql-9.3

There is a `point` column in a table. I need to add another `point`. The new point can not be nearer than a certain distance from the existing points. The distance is given by the `<@>` operator of the `earthdistance` extension.

This query returns the candidate point if there is no existing points nearer than 1 and an arbitrary point otherwise.

```
select
    case when not exists (
        select 1
        from (values ('0.01, 0'::point), ('-0.01, 0'), ('0, 0.01')) s(location)
        where location <@> point (0,0) < 1
    )
    then point(0,0)
    else point(1,1)
    end
;
```

I need a query to return the nearest possible non existent point ("free slot") to the candidate point. In this example it would be ≅ (0, -0.0144733)

To create the earthdistance extension:

```
create extension cube;
create extension earthdistance;
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by this. It sounds like you've got a collection of points and given one specific point as an input you'd like to know which of the existing points is the closest to that input point? Like "select p from existing_points order by p <@> point(input_lat, input_lon) asc limit 1"?

Comment: @yieldsfalsehood No I want the nearest "free slot" to the input point.

Comment: Gotcha. Now can you clarify what makes (0, -0.0144733) that point in your example? There are infinitely many points near (0, 0) that are not in the set (0.01, 0), (-0.01, 0), (0, 0.01).